# Renaming folders in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a function which renames a folder, which getting from some Input form, and saved result storing at dlg.result. Chosen folder (his name), stored at selectedItems[0].
For example:
1) balancer/balancer/test.py --(change to main)--> main/balancer/test.py (OK!)
2) balancer/balancer/test.py --(change second folder name)--> balancer/main/test.py (doesn't worked)
How can I fix the second item?

```
...    
for root, subdir, files in os.walk(file_path):
    for filename in files:
        file_in_folder_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        file_hash, size = md5_for_file(file_in_folder_path)
        basic_folder = os.path.normpath(root) + '/'
        basic_folder = basic_folder.replace(defaultDir, '')
        new_path = basic_folder.replace(selectedItems[0], dlg.result, 1)
        new_path = new_path.replace(defaultDir, '')
        rnm_files.append((filename, basic_folder, file_hash, filename, new_path))
...
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. What do you want to happen? What *does* happen? Why is it wrong?

Comment: @Tichodroma I'm just want to rename any folder name to another folder name. If we rename the root directory, then everything will be as first example and some inner folder, it will be as second example. But i сan't implement the second situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for a way to rename a non-empty directory, use [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).  It will rename the directory, saving the contents of the directory in place. The new name for the directory shouldn't already exist or you'll run into trouble.

Here's a basic example.  Assuming that balancer is your current directory:

```
import shutil
shutil.move('balancer/', 'main/')
```

The parameters of the function are the file path (absolute or relative, both will work) of the source directory and the new name for the same path.  You don't need to do anything with the contents of these directories.